# Pass var to jQuery script

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, jquery, variable

I need to pass a php var to a jQuery script. They are in separate files, one file to php code and another file to jQuery scripts. Is there a way of doing it? I am using Joomla 3.4.1. I just need to get Joomla version in the jQuery script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript have global variables : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

inside you php file you call: *JFactory::getDocument();* and you can now add some javascript at the current page with *addScriptDeclaration()*

In this example, we declare a *myJoomlaVersion* variable

```
    <$php 
$jdocument = JFactory::getDocument(); 
$jversion = new JVersion(); 
$short = $jversion->getShortVersion(); 

// Add Javascript 
$jdocument->addScriptDeclaration(' var myJoomlaVersion = '.$short ); ?>
```

More info about "Inserting inline scripts from within a PHP file" https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page

Now you can use this variable into your javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm getting the following `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

Comment: I have edited my code. A small type on it
This new one should work better

Answer (score 9):

After this question was originally answered, Joomla introduced in version 3.5 another way of passing variables to javascript, using the `addScriptOptions()` method of the Joomla `Document` class. So I'm just adding this to make other people who are interested in this question aware of this alternative.

In your php file you can write eg:

```
$phpvars = array('alpha' => 1, 'beta' => 'test', 'gamma' => null);
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptOptions('myvars', $phpvars);
```

Then in your javascript you can retrieve the values using:

```
var jsvars = Joomla.getOptions('myvars');
console.log(jsvars);
```

which will output on the browser console the Javscript Object structure:

```
{alpha: 1, beta: "test", gamma: null}
```

You can obviously use this multiple times in your code, using different keys (the key being `'myvars'` in the example above).

Comment: Though this is a more recent addition to Joomla than the original answer, this is the correct answer for any modern Joomla component

Comment: @Robbie Jackson, I am trying to implement an Openlayer map into my application i accordance with your tutorial. In order to reduce overhead I need to compile an openlayers "bundle" in node.js but node.js does not know what "Joomla.getOptions" means. Do you happen to know how joomla has implemented this mechanism? Then I could probably create a "stub". Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SoaringBird as far as I remember, Joomla just puts these variables into a script tag which it embeds in the document. You should be able to see it via your browser devtools inspector. The Joomla.getOptions js code is in /media/system/js/core-uncompressed.js in your joomla (3.9 ish) instance. Looking at it, it does a document.querySelectorAll() call to find them, so I reckon you could replicate that code without a great deal of difficulty. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Robbie Jackson. We have been writing on our solutions simultaneously. I just updated my question at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28963/how-to-use-openlayers-compiled-javascript-code-in-my-own-extension with a solution I found myself but yours is better. You are definitely right in your tutorial at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_a_Map:  It takes a steep learning curve to get into Openlayers.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the use of a global function.

So, in your JS file, you would do something like this:

```
<script>
    var myFunction;

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        myFunction = function(version)
        {
            console.log(version);

            // You have the version here
        }

    });
</script>
```

Then, in your **default.php**, you can get the Joomla version and call the function like so:

```
<?php 
    $jversion = new JVersion(); 
    $short    = $jversion->getShortVersion();
?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        myFunction('<?php echo $short; ?>');

    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps