# How to pass variables/data to client javascript from Joomla component?

Tags: joomla-3.x

What is the proper way of passing variables from Joomla backend to javascript (frontend)? I have found examples simply setting the variables in templates like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var someVar = <?php echo $some_php_var ?>
</script>
```

Is there any other "standard" way of doing this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10558/pass-var-to-jquery-script/22278 See also Joomla doc at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page#Adding_the_Options_to_Your_JavaScript_Code. For more recent versions of Joomla I think you should use `addScriptOptions`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass var to jQuery script](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/10558/pass-var-to-jquery-script)